# Unable to start my nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi I am trying to start a node-js based application but it is giving me some mongodb based error and I can't seem to start my plugin.

Error:

```
/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:110
  if(host.indexOf('\/') != -1) {
          ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
    at new Server (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:110:11)
    at new MongoDB (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:51:18)
    at Object.initializeSchema [as initialize] (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:26:22)
    at new Schema (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/schema.js:106:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/app.js:56:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Here are the configurations I am currently using:
database.js

```
module.exports = {
    url : 'mongodb://localhost/test'
};
```

app.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/*var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)*/
var database = require('./config/database');
/*var port     = process.env.PORT || 8888;*/         // set the port

mongoose.connect(database.url);
console.log('Connected to Database: ' + database.url);

var Schema = require('jugglingdb').Schema;
var schema = new Schema('mongodb');

var schema = new Schema('mongodb', {
  url: 'mongodb://localhost/test',
});
```

I am also using jugglingdb as crossDb ORM in my application

config.json

```
"store": {
  "adapter": "jugglingdb",
  "type": "mongodb"

},
```

After I implemented the suggestions provided the errors has completely changed:

```
Unhandled error: TypeError: Cannot call 

    method 'indexOf' of undefined
        at new Server (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:110:11)
        at new MongoDB (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:51:18)
        at Object.initializeSchema [as initialize] (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:26:22)
        at new Schema (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/schema.js:105:13)
        at /home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/store/jugglingdb.js:34:32
        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$initializePromise (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:541:9)
        at new lib$rsvp$promise$$Promise (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:757:9)
        at new JugglingDB (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/store/jugglingdb.js:32:18)
        at module.exports (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/store/jugglingdb.js:168:10)
        at Function.stores.create (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/store/index.js:18:10)
        at stores (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/store/index.js:12:17)
        at EventEmitter.Addon (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/index.js:31:38)
        at module.exports (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/index.js:204:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/app.js:32:13)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    Unhandled error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
        at JugglingDB.proto.isMemoryStore (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/store/jugglingdb.js:78:29)
        at EventEmitter.exports.shouldRegister (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/internal/registration.js:45:67)
        at /home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/lib/internal/registration.js:85:54
        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:493:16)
        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:505:17)
        at /home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1001:13
        at Object.lib$rsvp$asap$$flush [as _onImmediate] (/home/jira-Plugins/cloud/test-plugin/node_modules/atlassian-connect-express/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Comment: Obvious question... where is "host" defined?

Comment: Try removing the line `var schema = new Schema('mongodb');`. The `Schema` constructor expects the connection options object.

Comment: @jmargolisvt, somewhere in the library. I don't think he directly calls the function that throws the error

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include any info on what is in line 56 of your app.js.

The error looks like the mongodb driver is trying to find a slash in a variable called `host` and fails to do so because the `host` is undefined.

Isn't it because you have `var schema` defined twice?

```
var schema = new Schema('mongodb');

var schema = new Schema('mongodb', {
  url: 'mongodb://localhost/test',
});
```

Maybe remove the first one where you don't have the `url`.

Also, are you using both Mongoose and JugglingDB in the same program?

Comment: line 56 is having var schema = new Schema('mongodb');

Comment: After I removed the first one var schema = new Schema('mongodb') the error went away but now getting a new error.     throw MongoError.create({message: 'port must be specified', driver:true});
                     ^
MongoError: port must be specified

Comment: try including port in the url - like - url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'.

Comment: Now the error has completely changed : updated the question